# PHP (Moodle) variables $USER->name used in queries

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, moodle

**Background:**
On our site students are enrolling themselves via an automated system in another CMS and only username, email and password are set up. This means their first and last name are something like 'default' or whatever but this needs to be changed - students need to be forced to change their details on log in.

**Problem:**
I was writing some code that did a header redirect:

```
if($PAGE->title != "Edit Profile" && $USER->lastname = "changeme") 
{header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/user/edit.php' )}
```

However although this works for a few initial clicks, the lastname is changed back to "changeme" and thus the person is stuck on the edit profile page (edit.php).

Is there a way I can get the lastname of the student as a variable so I can run the query if(lastname = "changeme") without the lastname being changed?

Or is there another solution to the problem altogether? (getting the student to change First and Last name on first time entering the site?

thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I can use a 'less than symbol' which works better. Make Last Name "1" and then execute the code

```
if($PAGE->title != "Edit Profile" && $USER->lastname < "2")
```

We are testing this but it seems to work. Ultimately we are looking at a much more advanced integration of Drupal Commerce and Moodle.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contained an assignment. You should have used "==" instead of "=" as below:

```
if($PAGE->title != "Edit Profile" && $USER->lastname == "changeme")
```

Answer (score 0):

What CMS are you using?

Does your CMS ask for the first and last names?

You might be able to integrate it with Moodle

http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Integrations

There are a few authentication settings too if you haven't already looked at these

http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Managing_authentication#Profile_fields_data_mapping_and_locking

Comment: We are using Drupal but we have found a temporary solution. Thanks